# Why spec does not see the class in the module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I trying to test my app, and when I do this

spec/support/devise_models.rb

```
module DeviseModels
  class UserWithCustomEncryption < User
    protected
    def password_digest(password)
      password.reverse
    end
  end
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include DeviseModels
  ...
```

and when I call in my spec

```
UserWithCustomEncryption.new
```

shell show me an error

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant UserWithCustomEncryption
```

and when I include this module on the top in my spec, its work well.how fix?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its namespaced, use `DeviseModels::UserWithCustomEncryption.new`